# Efficient method to find the index of 4-char string among all possible 4-char strings with given letters

Tags: python, string, combinatorics, cartesian-product

This:

```
A = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!'
n = len(A)

def f(s):
    t = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        t += A.index(c) * n ** (3 - i)
    return t

print(f(b'aaaa'))  # first possible 4-char string, should be 0
print(f(b'aaab'))  # 2nd possible 4-char string, should be 1
print(f(b'!!!!'))  # last possible 4-char string, should be 37^4 - 1
```

works to find the index of a 4-char string among all possible 4-char strings made with an alphabet `A`, but it does not seem efficient because of the many `A.index()` calls.

**How to speed-efficiently find the index of a 4-char string among all possible 4-char strings made with an alphabet `A`?**

Comment: You only make four calls per 4-letter sequence, that is going to be as efficient as it gets I think. The only thing you could improve is for longer sequences, check if a letter appears more than once to save a few calls. If you want raw speed, you should either make a lookup table or not use Python. Also, A is a global and therefore evil.

Comment: yes `A` global is not a problem, I just did it here for a MCVE. Finding the index `A.index()` for each char is probably not efficient, I guess we can do better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean, the only way I can think of is using a stupid branchless formula to calculate the index as-is, but I have nothing else to offer you.

```
A = b'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789!'
n = len(A)

def f(s,A):
    t = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        t += A.index(c) * n ** (3 - i)
    return t

def g(s,A):
    t = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(s):
        t += (c - 97 + (c<97)*75 + (c<48)*25) * n ** (3 - i)
    return t


print(f(b'aaaa',A),g(b'aaaa',A))  # first possible 4-char string, should be 0
print(f(b'aaab',A),g(b'aaab',A))  # 2nd possible 4-char string, should be 1
print(f(b'!!!!',A),g(b'!!!!',A))  # last possible 4-char string, should be 37^4 - 1

import timeit
ft = timeit.timeit(lambda: 'f(b"aop!")',number=1000000)
gt = timeit.timeit(lambda: 'g(b"aop!")',number=1000000)
print(f'f: {ft}, g: {gt}, factor: {ft/gt}')
```

Output:

```
0 0
1 1
1874160 1874160
f: 0.12712620000820607, g: 0.06313459994271398, factor: 2.0135741752312635
```

**Edit**: I tried one other thing:

```
def h(s):
    arr = np.array(list(s))
    return sum( (arr - 97 + (arr<97)*75 + (arr<48)*25) * n ** (3 - np.array([0,1,2,3])) )
```

Output:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
1874160 1874160 1874160
f: 0.10835059999953955, g: 0.07444929995108396, h: 0.06341919989790767,
factor f/g: 1.4553608975602195, factor f/h: 1.7084826073801391
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're concerned with the speed efficiency of your code. The `A.index()` is only executed once for each character, so 4 times in your example.
Of course you could make that more speed efficiently by using a dictionary. So, first creating a dictionary like:

```
alphabet_index_lookup = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, ..., '!': 37}
```

and then use that to lookup the index of the character. This is significantly faster, because python internally uses a hash-map to find the key instead of just iterating through the list. More background & comparison: https://towardsdatascience.com/faster-lookups-in-python-1d7503e9cd38

But like previously mentioned: Unless you're applying `f()` for really long strings, it won't make a significant difference.

Comment: Thanks @ThoPaz. Yes I'm using `f()` for millions of strings, thus the search for efficiency.

Comment: That makes sense! Then this lookup_dict would be very useful, especially since it's super small in comparison to the win of execution time.